# How to access Terraform module in AWS CodeArtifact

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-codeartifact

I created a Terraform module and stored the *.tar.gz file in AWS CodeArtifact. Now I want to access that module in a subsequent Terraform module like this:

```
module "foo" {
   source = "<some url that points to TF module stored in CodeArtifact>"
}
```

When I look at the entry in CodeArtifact, I don't see any URL or endpoint construct that I can use to download/access.  Can I not store TF modules in CodeArtifact, using them in other TF modules?  Is it only for storing upstream packages used in clients such as npm or maven? Do I need to go to something such as Artifactory or some other software package storage mechanism (I was trying to stay within the AWS ecosphere)?

Comment: If you want to stay within the AWS ecosystem then why not use CodeCommit to store the module source code and then reference the module with a git URI in the declaration?

Comment: I could but AWS advertises CodeArtifact as an artifact repository similar to Artifactory or Nexus.  So, I wanted to try to use it as I would Artifactory and attempt to store a TF module.  If CodeArtifact is not similar, I can at least say to my client that CodeArtifact falls short in certain areas, here is one example.

Comment: Everyone is saying to use CodeCommit, but Terraform also supports pulling modules from S3 bucket sources, which may be easier to work with. In any case, I haven't used CodeArtifact, but the documentation does seem to indicate that you should be able to get an HTTPS URL for your artifact.

Comment: If so, I have not found that documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your terraform modules in AWS Codecommit.